# Defining label/s during create(node()) in batches

Tags: py2neo

As I understand from the documentation of py2neo, the only way to add a label to a node is to use the `add_labels()` function, after the node is created. Is there any way to define label/s in the `create(node())` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option right now is to use Cypher to create the node instead of the 'create' method. This is because the underlying REST resource does not support creation of nodes with labels. The next version of py2neo (currently in beta) will make the process slightly simpler, allowing labels to be used through the 'create' method by wrapping Cypher directly instead.

Comment: AFAIK, the answer above applies to py2neo 1.6. Has anything changed now with py2neo 2.0?

Comment: It has and labels can now be added to nodes on creation. A summary of the changes for 2.0 are here -> http://neo4j.com/blog/py2neo-2-0-unleashed/

Answer (score 1):

You can [now](http://neo4j.com/blog/py2neo-2-0-unleashed/) add labels to nodes when you create them.

From the [docs](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#nodes):

```
from py2neo import Node
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
banana = Node("Fruit", "Food", colour="yellow", tasty=True)
```